# Calculate conditional expectation of standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory

**Exercise**

Let $X,Y$ be independent standard normal random variables.

Calculate the conditional expectation

$$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}]$$

where $\mathcal{P} = \sigma(X)$

**Attempt**

$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}] = E[X^3|\mathcal{P}] + E[Y^3|\mathcal{P}] + 3E[X^2Y|\mathcal{P}] + 3E[XY^2|\mathcal{P}]$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X^2$ is indepentent of $Y$ and $Y^2$ is indepentent of $X$ (is this correct?)

Then
$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}] = E[X^3|\mathcal{P}] + E[Y^3|\mathcal{P}] + 3E[X^2|\mathcal{P}] E[Y|\mathcal{P}]+ 3E[Y^2|\mathcal{P}] E[X|\mathcal{P}]$

To continue, I used the following, which is what I have understood:

i) If $X$ is $\mathcal{P}$-metrizable then $E[X|\mathcal{P}] = X$. (Since $\mathcal{P} = \sigma(X)$ then I understand that $X$ is $\mathcal{P}$-metrizable)

ii) If $\mathcal{P} = \sigma(X)$ then $E[Y|\mathcal{P}] = E[Y|X]$ for $Y$ random variable.

Continuing my attempt,
$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}] = X^3 + E[Y^3|X] + 3X^2E[Y|X] +3XE[Y^2|X]$

Again, since $X,Y$ are independent, I suppose $Y^3,X$ independent and $Y^2,X$ independent.

Therefore,

$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}] = X^3 + E[Y^3] + 3X^2E[Y] +3XE[Y^2]$

But, $Y$ is a standard normal random variable so $E[Y] = 0$. Here I also suppose that this means that $E[Y^3] = 0$ and $E[Y^2] = 0$. (Is this correct?)

This leaves us with the result,
$E[\left(X+Y\right)^3|\mathcal{P}] = X^3$

I am not too confident about the assumptions I made and the procedure. Does someone have any hints?

Comment: The independence assumptions are all correct. However, for a standard normal random variable, we have, $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = 1$ and not $0$..

Comment: @sudeep5221 Seems more logical for it to be non zero now that I think about it. So I should prove this using $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f(x) dx$ right? Also I should do the same for $E[Y^3]$. (I think that it will be $E[Y^n] = 1$ if $n$ is even and $E[Y^n] = 0$ if $n$ is odd?)

Comment: The general answer to the moments can be found here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments . Whether you need to prove entirely depends on the context. If this is a homework problem and the specific values of the moments have not been discussed, then you should prove. If they are assumed to be known then it is fine if you don't. Also if you are not familiar with such results, it is a good exercise to prove these results.